How does my Service plug into my Child Component
I'm an old hand at AngularJS, and now cutting my teeth once again on Angular, with the new standalone (incase its relevant) and considering how to hook my data from my firebase service to my display child component.
service->app->page->display
Hoping its just a simple answer that my google-foo has failed to discover.
The Service:
public getMenu(): Observable<menuItem[]> {

    const local = collectionData(this.menuCollection, {
        idField: 'id'
    }) as Observable<menuItem[]>;

    local.subscribe((list) => {
        this.menuList = list;  // its either this to a local
    })

    return this.menuList; // or this returned locally to service
}

i.e. this.menuList = this.getMenu();

The Page Controller:
this.menuList: menuItem[] = this.firebaseService.getMenu(); 

     // I think this is wrong.. I don't want to store a copy, I want it linked to the Service

The Page HTML
<header [menuList]="menuList"></header>

And the Display component (Header)
@Input() menuList: menuItem[] = [];

with its template just displaying
<div *ngFor="let item of menuList; index as i;">{{item}}</div>

Page, is storing this.menuList
I expect, if the database changes, the Observable updates the menuList in services, which passes down the data to the pages menuList, which passes down to the template and it updates.
But instead, this.menuList is a copy locally in Page, and does not update.

As stated in this document, getMenu() should return observable and you should use async pipe in your template.
